# Neural Network for Matrix Eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, neural-network, pytorch, eigenvalue

I am interested in training a network that can take a square (symmetric, for the sake of real eigenvalues) 2x2 matrix as an input and output the corresponding eigenvalues.

So far I have attempted this using pytorch. I create a training set by randomly generating matrices and then using scipy.linalg to solve for the eignevalues:

```
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 2))
A = (A + A.T)/2 #Make the matrices symmetric
results = la.eig(A)
```

Training a CNN with pytorch **on a single input matrix**, it can achieve a ***high*** training set ***accuracy*** and approximate the eigenvalues well.

However when **using a training set** with two or more input matrices, the cost function decreases some, but the resulting eigenvalues have a ***low*** training set ***accuracy***.

I've tried changing the network depth/size, as well as just using a regular ANN instead of a CNN, but I am unable to achieve a low training set error when the training set contains more than one matrix.

Is there some fundamental reason why a NN is not able to be applied to this kind of problem? Or is it just a problem of my incorrect implementation?

Comment: googleing around there are a couple papers about the subject [maybe they can give a hint](https://www.google.com/search?q=neural+network+for+matrix+eigenvalues&oq=neural+network+for+matrix+eigenvalues&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but it seams that is more complex than just one CNN/ANN